# Python: Process in progress with start datetime and end datetime on hourly level

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, process, duration

I've been tracking my gaming sessions over the entire last year - just to have data I care about and to learn python.
Now I want to know (and plot - but not important yet) in which hours a played the most (hours: 0 to 23) over the entire time and over all activities - per day since tracking start.

Sample:

| session_id | game_id | start_datetime | end_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 74 | 2023-02-22 13:15:00 | 2023-02-22 15:30:00 |
| 002 | 127 | 2023-02-23 13:30:00 | 2023-02-23 13:45:00 |
| 003 | 74 | 2023-02-24 14:40:00 | 2023-02-24 15:00:00 |

In the end I want to see this info - calculation column not needed:

| hour_of_day | sum_hours_played | avg_hours_played_per_day | calculation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1.00 | 0.33 | (0.75 + 0.25) / 3 days |
| 14 | 1.33 | 0.44 | (1.00 + 0.33) / 3 days |
| 15 | 0.5 | 0.17 | (0.5) / 3 days |

In short, I don't just want to see in which hours I played (played: 1, not played 0) but also what proportion of the particular hour I played.

I saw some approaches on the web, but almost all of them just count / sum single yes or no events per month or day. They don't calculate proportions of a day/hour.

So, I'm glad about any tip you have where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load your data into a DataFrame
data = {
    'session_id': [1, 2, 3],
    'game_id': [74, 127, 74],
    'start_datetime': ['2023-02-22 13:15:00', '2023-02-23 13:30:00', '2023-02-24 14:40:00'],
    'end_datetime': ['2023-02-22 15:30:00', '2023-02-23 13:45:00', '2023-02-24 15:00:00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'start_datetime' and 'end_datetime' columns to datetime objects
df['start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_datetime'])
df['end_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_datetime'])

# Calculate the duration of each gaming session
df['duration'] = df['end_datetime'] - df['start_datetime']

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the hours played
hours_played = {i: 0 for i in range(24)}
```

The trick is to break each session into hours:

```
# Break down each session into hours and sum the proportion of hours played
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row['start_datetime']
    end = row['end_datetime']
    duration = row['duration']

    # Loop over the hours involved
    while start < end:

        # Calculate the end of the hour currently considered
        hour_start = start.replace(minute=0, second=0)
        hour_end = hour_start + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)

        played = min(hour_end, end) - start  # Here take what ends first (the hour or the session) and substract the start time
        hours_played[start.hour] += played.total_seconds() / 3600  # Here add the time played to the current value in the dictionary
        
        start = hour_end  # For the (possible) next iteration of the while look, set the start to the end of the hour currently considered

# Calculate the average hours played per day
total_days = (df['end_datetime'].max() - df['start_datetime'].min()).days + 1
avg_hours_played = {hour: hours / total_days for hour, hours in hours_played.items()}

# Create a DataFrame to display the results
results = pd.DataFrame(list(avg_hours_played.items()), columns=['hour_of_day', 'avg_hours_played_per_day'])
results['sum_hours_played'] = [hours_played[hour] for hour in results['hour_of_day']]
results = results[['hour_of_day', 'sum_hours_played', 'avg_hours_played_per_day']]
print(results)
```

I hope I have formulated my comments understandably

Comment: Hey hey DataJanitor, thank you for your help - I will try this out and let you know - I get the logic so far. This is a different approach I was thinking of though. In SQL I'd think of generate a hourly timeline (tl) first, then LEFT JOIN by whole hours WHERE md.with my data (md), and afterwards try with CASE WHEN to get the hour fractions for start_ and end_datetime...and for whole hours in between to take 1. I didn't think about to calculate the entire session duration.

Comment: I tried your approach but I'm stuck at df['duration']. I always get the Type Error what says I cannot use the operand on str and str. Both columns are converted to datetime64[ns], no NaTs, Nulls or wrong values..

Comment: @Don_Andrej Have you tried the code I provided? It should work fine, I can run it in jupyter notebook. If your code is not working, please prodive more information

Comment: I ffinally found some time to test the approach entirely and got it running. The results seem to be weitd though. :/ The avg_hours_played varries between 0.199xxx and 0.282xxx. There should be definitevely more difference since I never play in the middle of the night (e.g. 3AM: 0.19 vs 7PM: 0.25 and sum: 205 vs 264) Somewhere is a logic issue in the sum_hours_played calculation. However, this was a huge help though so far!

Comment: @Don_Andrej Glad I could help but it is unsatisfactory it doesn't run as expected. Is there any way you send me the input data, so I can check on the issue to deliver a solution?

Comment: Hi again, I found two issues with my data which messed up the calculation - first: I use the European date format and forgot to set dayfirst=True, second I had two rows where the filter I used was not set (so: wrong start date) - now it is working BUT: The sum_hours_played is exactly two times as high as in the actual data. For example: In the considered time I played exactly 1 hour between 2AM and 3AM - your "results" delivers 2 hours. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Oh god...I run the cell twice while trying...so the script did the sum calculation two times -.-' The problem is solved! Thank you! :)